# how open image in edit mode android programatically

Tags: android

I want to open image in edit mode, the following code opens image in gallery view but it do not have edit option on 5.0 OS. on kitkat it is working fine.

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Draft Images");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");
        }
    }
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.eye_template_c);
    File f = new File(mediaStorageDir, "test.png");
    try {
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
    filePath = f.getPath();
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "image/png");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Instead of `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` try `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

Comment: I have tried it but still getting same options for ACTION_VIEW

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly welcome to try `ACTION_EDIT`. However, few Android devices will have an app installed that supports image editing. You will want to have some sort of a fallback plan, such as suggesting an image editor app to the user, for the user to install.

Comment: If i add ACTION_EDIT it opens image with default image editor which do not have facility to write or draw on image. It do not show options to choose image editor app for ACTION_EDIT

Comment: @Yogi: There are ~2 billion Android devices, made up of thousands of device models. There is no "default image editor". Different device models may or may not have an app that supports `ACTION_EDIT` for `image/png`, and those that do have such an app will offer varying features. If you want image-editing capability, either implement it yourself, or identify some image editor that you can integrate with. Do not assume that a user will have an image editor of any form on their device.